# Trying to pin down the source of my Blue Screens

Tags: windows-8, drivers, bsod

So I just built a new computer the other day, and was able to run for several hours just fine. This included web browsing and listening to music. However, once I began playing video games everything became a bit crazy. I got two almost immediate back to back BSOD after only 10-20 minutes of playing a game. Usually I am able to pin down a BSOD to the Graphics Driver or the Sound driver, but I have updated both and clean installed both with no real difference. I have cleaned the machine (note that it is new so there is not much to clean) and done a system restore but I still get the same two BSODs.

Here is a link to the two most recent BSODs (from yesterday, I did not retain the previous ones)

https://www.dropbox.com/s/mmii5s2lqt9x808/Minidump_Raven.zip

Any suggestions? Note, I ran Memtest86 yesterday before the clean install and will not be able to run it again until tonight when I get home.

EDIT: Just a comment, but the boot drive is a Mushkin SSD and the Game is on a WD Green (5400 RPM) drive. I thought it would be good to post this since someone who answered below mentioned one of the dumps points to a possible HD problem. Thanks!

Comment: The dump file is great.  But the information on the BSOD itself would be helpfu.  Use a program like BlueScreenViewer to provide that information to us.

Comment: One thing you might want to try is to look up the data re: cas latency etc on your memory, and then in your motherboard BIOS, manually set this information rather than leaving it set to "auto". Do this especially if your memory is mismatched. If this has no positive impact, try retarding the timings a little (such as set CAS to 9 instead of 8.5.).

Comment: All I get is: 

BugCheck A, {fffffa80b2a2af08, 2, 0, fffff802580b2a31}

Probably caused by : memory_corruption ( nt!MiImagePageOk+41 )

Comment: @horatio I already did that when I built the computer. Its one of the first things I checked. The kit is a Mushkin Blackline 1600MHz with a Cas of 8 (8-8-8-24) so that was all squared away at the first boot. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

1 dumps shows a memory corruption :

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL (a)
An attempt was made to access a pageable (or completely invalid) address at an
interrupt request level (IRQL) that is too high.  This is usually
caused by drivers using improper addresses.
If a kernel debugger is available get the stack backtrace.
Arguments:
Arg1: fffffa80b2a2af08, memory referenced
Arg2: 0000000000000002, IRQL
Arg3: 0000000000000000, bitfield :
    bit 0 : value 0 = read operation, 1 = write operation
    bit 3 : value 0 = not an execute operation, 1 = execute operation (only on chips which support this level of status)
Arg4: fffff802580b2a31, address which referenced memory

Debugging Details:
------------------


READ_ADDRESS: GetPointerFromAddress: unable to read from fffff80258366168
GetUlongFromAddress: unable to read from fffff802583661f8
 fffffa80b2a2af08 Nonpaged pool

CURRENT_IRQL:  2

FAULTING_IP: 
nt!MiImagePageOk+41
fffff802`580b2a31 488b11          mov     rdx,qword ptr [rcx]

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  AV

PROCESS_NAME:  RzSynapse.exe

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 6.3.9431.0 (debuggers(dbg).130615-1214) amd64fre

TRAP_FRAME:  fffff880230bc580 -- (.trap 0xfffff880230bc580)
NOTE: The trap frame does not contain all registers.
Some register values may be zeroed or incorrect.
rax=0000000000000000 rbx=0000000000000000 rcx=fffffa80b2a2af08
rdx=fffffa800325f110 rsi=0000000000000000 rdi=0000000000000000
rip=fffff802580b2a31 rsp=fffff880230bc710 rbp=fffff880230bc7b0
 r8=0000058000000000  r9=fffffa80158d3e28 r10=0000000000000000
r11=00000000f8a003ee r12=0000000000000000 r13=0000000000000000
r14=0000000000000000 r15=0000000000000000
iopl=0         nv up ei ng nz na pe nc
nt!MiImagePageOk+0x41:
fffff802`580b2a31 488b11          mov     rdx,qword ptr [rcx] ds:fffffa80`b2a2af08=????????????????
Resetting default scope

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff80258067769 to fffff80258068440

STACK_TEXT:  
fffff880`230bc438 fffff802`58067769 : 00000000`0000000a fffffa80`b2a2af08 00000000`00000002 00000000`00000000 : nt!KeBugCheckEx
fffff880`230bc440 fffff802`58065fe0 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`70a5a5a0 00000001`00000000 fffff880`230bc580 : nt!KiBugCheckDispatch+0x69
fffff880`230bc580 fffff802`580b2a31 : 00000001`07ce9025 00000000`00000001 00000000`00002596 fffff802`5809d745 : nt!KiPageFault+0x260
fffff880`230bc710 fffff802`580a4185 : 00000000`00000000 fffff802`580e3241 00000000`00000000 fffff880`230bc850 : nt!MiImagePageOk+0x41
fffff880`230bc740 fffff802`5809f34f : 00000000`00000000 00000000`70a5a5a0 fffffa80`0301c290 fffffa80`158d3e28 : nt!MiResolveTransitionFault+0xf5
fffff880`230bc7e0 fffff802`5809b132 : fffff880`230bca88 00000000`70a5a5a0 fffff680`003852d0 fffffa80`158d3e28 : nt!MiResolveProtoPteFault+0x4cf
fffff880`230bc880 fffff802`580a27f9 : fffffa80`1432e080 00000000`00000000 fffff880`230bcb00 fffff880`230bca50 : nt!MiDispatchFault+0x272
fffff880`230bc9c0 fffff802`58065eee : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000001 fffff880`230bcb00 : nt!MmAccessFault+0x289
fffff880`230bcb00 00000000`70934daa : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiPageFault+0x16e
00000000`082bd33c 00000000`00000000 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : 0x70934daa


STACK_COMMAND:  kb

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
nt!MiImagePageOk+41
fffff802`580b2a31 488b11          mov     rdx,qword ptr [rcx]

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  3

SYMBOL_NAME:  nt!MiImagePageOk+41

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: nt

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  51a966cd

IMAGE_VERSION:  6.2.9200.16628

IMAGE_NAME:  memory_corruption

BUCKET_ID_FUNC_OFFSET:  41

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  AV_nt!MiImagePageOk
```

This can be a RAM or HDD issue. So run memtest86+ to test the RAM and a HDD diag tool to test the HDD.

The 2nd dump shows an issue with the Intel network driver e1d63x64.sys:

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

BAD_POOL_CALLER (c2)
The current thread is making a bad pool request.  Typically this is at a bad IRQL level or double freeing the same allocation, etc.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000007, Attempt to free pool which was already freed
Arg2: 00000000000011c1, (reserved)
Arg3: 0000000001500743, Memory contents of the pool block
Arg4: fffffa80127c6640, Address of the block of pool being deallocated

Debugging Details:
------------------


POOL_ADDRESS:  fffffa80127c6640 Nonpaged pool

FREED_POOL_TAG:  Ntfx

BUGCHECK_STR:  0xc2_7_Ntfx

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT

PROCESS_NAME:  System

CURRENT_IRQL:  2

TAG_NOT_DEFINED_c000000f:  FFFFF80331124FB0

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff8032f87ea6e to fffff8032f666440

STACK_TEXT:  
nt!KeBugCheckEx
nt!ExFreePool
Ndu!PplGenericFreeFunction
Ndu!NduDeleteNblContext
Ndu!NduHandleNblContextRemoved
Ndu!NduNblNotifyCallback
fwpkclnt!FwppNetBufferListEventNotify
NETIO!WfpNblInfoCleanup
ndis!NdisFreeNetBufferList
tcpip!TcpTcbSendDatagramsComplete
NETIO!NetioDereferenceNetBufferListChain
tcpip!FlSendNetBufferListChainComplete
ndis!ndisMSendCompleteNetBufferListsInternal
ndis!ndisInvokeNextSendCompleteHandler
ndis!NdisMSendNetBufferListsComplete
e1d63x64
0x0




STACK_COMMAND:  kb

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
Ndu!PplGenericFreeFunction+2f
fffff880`1ee0b807 eb0c            jmp     Ndu!PplGenericFreeFunction+0x3d (fffff880`1ee0b815)


FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  0xc2_7_Ntfx_Ndu!PplGenericFreeFunction



    Loaded symbol image file: e1d63x64.sys
    Image path: \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\e1d63x64.sys
    Image name: e1d63x64.sys
    Timestamp:        Wed Jan 23 17:39:53 2013
```

Comment: OK, that looks like a pretty good start, but I'd be surprised if MemTest came up with anything, but anything is possible. I'll run Memtest and a Hard Drive check tonight when I get the chance. Any suggestions with the Intel Driver? I can uninstall and reinstall to see if that makes any difference but it may not actually make much of a difference. I also have Killer NIC on that board so I can also just switch Ethernet ports I suppose...

Comment: look if there is a newer version of this driver.

Comment: Did you ever solve that?

Comment: @cxxl if you also have this driver in dmp, look for a driver update